# Problema con etiqueta audio a la hora de reproducir en telefonos iOS

Tags: ios, audio, sonido

Tengo unos problemas con respecto a la etiqueta audio, espero que alguien tenga tiempo de leer esto y ayudarme porque es un poco complejo. Estoy realizando un sitio web de la radio de mi padre, pude realizarlo sin ningún problema (estoy seguro que encontraran muchos errores y cosas mejorables, pero es mi primer sitio que hago oficialmente). El problema es que al ingresar a la pagina desde el sistema operativo iOS y darle al botón de play no sucede nada (en cambio en pc funciona sin problema). Les cuento también que el audio de este sitio esta sacado de otra pagina que ofrece servicio de streaming para la radio (Listen2MyRadio). El esquema sería: Radio-Listen2MyRadio-SitioWeb. Se me ha ocurrido todo y no he podido solucionarlo, por eso recurrí a crearme una cuenta y postear aquí, buscando información me encontré con que para que el audio funcione en el móvil hay que convertir el audio entrante en un formato especial, el problema es que como dije anteriormente, el audio proviene de otra página (es decir una IP) y no se como podría convertir ese audio en otro formato. Aclaro que esta es una idea subjetiva y que no estoy seguro si esto solucionaría del todo el problema. Desde ya gracias y me parece mas cómodo dejarles la raíz que subí a mediafire para que puedan probarlo. Espero respuesta por mas simple que sea. Un saludo!

http://www.mediafire.com/file/xh1bfzlcrjhrmgh/raizRadio_22-01_%2528ACTUAL%2529.rar/file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Ciudad del Colla FM</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/circNaranja.ico">        

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_RadioCDC.css">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#E8E8E8">


<div id="cabecera">



<div id="logo"><img src="imagenes/logo.png" width="180" height="90">

</div>






<div id="barraRedes">

<div id="redSocial">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Ciudaddelcolla/">
<img src="imagenes/facebook.png" width="45px" height="45px">
</a>

  </div>
<div id="redSocial">
<a href="https://twitter.com/Fm973rc">
<img src="imagenes/twitter.png" width="45px" height="45px">
</a>
</div>
<div id="redSocial">
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/f97.3/">
<img src="imagenes/instagram.png" width="45px" height="45px">
</a>
    </div>


</div>

</div>

</div>



<div id="reproductor">

<div id="volumeBar">
<input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="10">
</div>

<div id="button">
<button id="play"> <img src="imagenes/player/play1.png" width="70px" height="70px"</button>
</div>

<div id="button">
<button id="soundOn"> <img src="imagenes/player/audio.png" width="40px" height="40px"</button>
</div>

<div id="button">
<button id="pause"> <img src="imagenes/player/pause.png" width="70px" height="70px"</button>
</div>

<div id="button">
<button id="soundOff"> <img src="imagenes/player/muted.png" width="40px" height="40px"</button>
</div>
<div id="linkCel">

<a href="http://fm973ciudaddelcolla.myl2mr.com/" style="color:#000000;"> ¿Problemas al reproducir? </a>

</div>



<audio id="emision">
<source src="http://109.169.37.137:10211/;stream.nsv" type="audio/mp3"></source></audio>


</div>




<div id="line_bar">
</div>



<div id = "menu_bar">

<div id="enlaces">
<a href="index.html" style="color:#000000;  text-decoration:none;"> INICIO </a>

</div>




</div>



<div id="line_bar">

</div>


<div id="mantenimiento">
<h1> SITIO EN CONSTRUCCIÓN </h1>
<br>
<h2> Radio Ciudad del Colla FM | Desde Rosario al mundo </h2>
<br>
<br>
Celular 099430577 Teléfono 455 21369 </h3>
</h3>
</div>





<p>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">

        </script>
</p>
<p>
  <script src="js/main.js">


        </script>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
// JavaScript Document

    var soundOff = document.getElementById('soundOff');
    $('#soundOff').hide();

    var pause = document.getElementById('pause');
    $('#pause').hide();

window.onload = function(){

    var audio = document.getElementById('emision');
    var play = document.getElementById('play');
    var soundOn = document.getElementById('soundOn');

    $('#volume').change(function(){

        audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value/10);

    });

    soundOn.addEventListener("click", function(){

        $('#soundOn').hide();
        $('#soundOff').show();
        audio.muted=true;

    });


    soundOff.addEventListener("click", function(){

        $('#soundOff').hide();
        $('#soundOn').show();
        audio.muted=false;

    });

    play.addEventListener("click", function(){

        $('#play').hide();
        $('#pause').show();
        audio.play();
            })

            pause.addEventListener("click", function(){

        $('#pause').hide();
        $('#play').show();
        audio.pause();

    });

}
```

Comment: Parece más un problema de la Web que de el propio sistema iOS, has probado a ejecutarlo desde un teléfono Android?

Comment: Gracias por responder! Si, en android funciona perfectamente. Está subido actualmente a www.ciudaddelcollafm.com